# How can I temporarily disable all local notification scheduled by my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

Is there any method to temporarily disable all local notifications created by an iPhone app? I need to re enable them all with respect to a condition. my requirement is if the user turned off the notification button on my app , then no more notifications is shown.If he turned it on   then all notifications should be shown. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all scheduled notifications and save them in shared preferences for example.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]     scheduledLocalNotifications];
```

Then cancel all notifications:

```
- (void)cancelLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

If user activate notifications again, you can reschedule them again.

Comment: Or simply recompute the require notifications when re-enabling.

Comment: How can I re enable them all?

Comment: Load previously saved date and create new notifications.
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

Comment: Its not possible to get the previous dates

Answer (score 0):

You can use "cancelAllLocalNotifications" method and When User turn it On you can set again All notification for it.